# Combinatorics : dividing people into groups

Tags: combinatorics

A group of 7 people is going to be divided in 4 groups, three of which of size 2. The order of the people within a group does not matter and groups can only be told apart in view of their sizes. How many ways are there to do so?

I know this is an easy question and my answer is 630 but I can't help but think the meaning of the phrase "groups can only be told apart in view of their sizes".

I sincerely hope it doesn't change the answer.

Comment: It means that they are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid the answer **does change**, because  $3\;$ of the groups are indistinguishable (unlabelled).

The answer thus should be $\dfrac{630}{3!} = 105$

The reason may be clearer if we consider one such division
We would consider $AB\; |\; CD \;|\; EF\;|\;G\; $, and, say $\;CD\; |\;EF\;|AB\;|\; G$ **to be identical divisions.**

Using permutations, we would write the answer as $\;\dfrac{7!}{(2!2!2!1!)\times(3!)}$

The denominator's first part removes permutations **within** groups,
and the $3!$ removes those **between** groups

Comment: Yes youre right ignore my answer

Answer (score 0):

We choose two people from group of 7 people because it is a one-to-one function$f:\{1,2\} \xrightarrow{\rm 1:1} \{1,2,...,7\}$, then we multiply it by 5 choose 2 because we have left 5 people etc. $$\binom{7}{2} \cdot \binom{5}{2} \cdot \binom{3}{2}$$